# How to populate listview from two sqlite table rows in listview in Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have to retrieve the JSON String and update,insert and retrieve the record one by one from two different SQLite table.But how to show the retrieved data from two different table in list view by concatenating and then add one by one in list-view.Can someone suggest me how to do this?

Here is my code

```
 private class GetAllActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllPosts_Page.this);
                pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
            {
                getAllActivityList();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();
            if ( pDialog!=null && pDialog.isShowing() )
            {
                pDialog.cancel();

                ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_AllPost);
                MyListAdapter adapter = new       
                MyListAdapter(this,R.layout.all_post_row,str);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }


     public void getAllActivityList()
        {
            String strUrl_GetAll_Activity = "http://xxxx/xxx/xxx.svc/xxx/Sync_Time/null/xxx/xxxx-xxxx";
            Log.e("strUrl_GetAll_Activity ", " = " + strUrl_GetAll_Activity);

            InputStream inputStream = null;

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(strUrl_GetAll_Activity));
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                if(inputStream != null)
                    strResult = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
                else
                    strResult = "Did not work!";

                String jsonStr = strResult;
                Log.e("Get_Vessels_By_Type  "," = " + jsonStr);

                if(jsonStr != null)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                        String jsonResult = jsonObj.toString().trim();
                        Log.e("jsonResult ", " = " + jsonResult);

                        JSONObject getAllActivity_List = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Get_ALL_ActivityListResult");
                        Log.e("getAllActivity_List ", " = " + getAllActivity_List.toString());

                        String strSync = getAllActivity_List.getString("Sync_Time");
                        Log.e("strSync ", " = " + strSync.toString());

                        JSONArray jarr = getAllActivity_List.getJSONArray("ActivityList");
                        Log.e("jarr ", " = " + jarr.toString());

                        for (int j = 0; j < jarr.length(); j++)
                        {
                            JSONObject jobjVessels = jarr.getJSONObject(j);

                            strActivityId = jobjVessels.getString("activityId");
                            strRemark = jobjVessels.getString("remark");
                            strName = jobjVessels.getString("name");
                            strStatus = jobjVessels.getString("status");
                            strType = jobjVessels.getString("type");
                            strUserId = jobjVessels.getString("userId");
                            strObjectId = jobjVessels.getString("objectId");
                            strActiondate = jobjVessels.getString("actionDate");
                            strStarFlag= jobjVessels.getString("StarFlag");




                            if(dbhelper.isAllPostId_Exist(strActivityId))
                            {
                                //Upadte
                                Log.e("*******************", "*******************");
                                dbhelper.update_AllPost(strActivityId, strRemark, strName, strStatus, strType, strUserId, strObjectId, strActiondate, strStarFlag);
                                Log.e("Data updated in ", "Company Table !!");
                                Log.e("*******************", "*******************");
                            }
                            else
                            {

                                Log.e("*******************", "*******************");
                                dbhelper.insert_AllPost(strActivityId, strRemark, strName, strStatus, strType, strUserId, strObjectId, strActiondate, strStarFlag);
                                Log.e("Dats save in ", "AllPost Succesively !!!!");
                                Log.e("*******************", "*******************");

                            }

                            Log.e("*******After Else******", "*******************");
                            getInspectorName(strUserId);

                            Log.e("*******************", "*******************");
                            getVesselName(strObjectId);
                        }

                    }
                    catch(JSONException je)
                    {
                    je.printStackTrace();}
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Here to fetch the specific row

```
public String getInspectorName(String strInspectorId)
        {
            Cursor cursor = null;

            SQLiteDatabase mDb = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
            try{

                cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select Inspector_name from Inspector where Inspector_Id=?", new String[] {strInspectorId + ""});

                if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    inspectorName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Inspector_name"));

                    Log.e(" inspectorName "," = " + inspectorName);
                }

                return inspectorName;
            }finally {

                cursor.close();
            }

        }


        public String getVesselName(String strVesselIdId)
        {
            Cursor cursor = null;

            SQLiteDatabase mDb = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
            try{

                cursor = mDb.rawQuery("select Vessel_Name from VesselList where Vessel_ID=?", new String[] {strVesselIdId + ""});

                if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {

                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    inVesselName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Vessel_Name"));
                    Log.e(" inVesselName "," = " + inVesselName);
                }

                return inVesselName;
            }finally {

                cursor.close();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Join for fetching data from two tables

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_joins.htm
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

**NOTE** : For applying join you must have some common id for both tables.